# Не могу в SourceTree подключить свой аккаунт GitHub

Tags: bitbucket, git, github

На гитхабе у меня есть репозиторий. Я склонировал его через SourceTree, но когда хочу загрузить изменения на сервер, просит авторизоваться. Ввожу логин и пароль 100% правильно. Но выдает [ошибку](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6XqIlzHy8Q9UjE0azhNSkc0Sjg/view?usp=sharing). Может потому что у меня на гитхабе еще включена авторизация через смс?

Только знакомлюсь с Bitbucket и SourceTree.

Comment: Вы бы ещё через ментальный канал включили авторизацию.

Для работы с гитхабом используйте либо консольные утилиты, либо его родной клиент. А SourceTree - в топку.

Comment: Я просто сейчас изучаю работу с Bitbucket и SourceTree. Обычно я через родной клиент и работаю

Comment: так битбакет или гитхаб?

Comment: Создал тестовый проект на гитхабе, склонировал его через SoutceTree к себе на компьютер. Внес изменения и хочу отправить эти изменения обратно на гитхаб. Но выдает ошибку авторизации

Comment: у Вас, похоже, виндовс, тогда самый простой способ - это использовать [родной клиент](https://windows.github.com/) или использовать консоль.

А так, похоже, что у Вас не настроены нормально ключи для авторизации.

Comment: Попробуйте зайти на битбакет и прикрепить к своему аккаунту аккаунт гитхаба. Потом зайдите в настройки гитхаба, раздел `Applications`, там должен быть разрешен доступ к Bitbucket. Возможно,  поможет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В случае с двухфакторной вы можете [создать токен](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-an-access-token-for-command-line-use/), что бы использовать вместо пароля без необходимости получать коды в sms.

Так же есть [инструкция от GitHub](https://github.com/GSoft-SharePoint/Dynamite/wiki/Getting-started-with-SourceTree,-Git-and-git-flow)